# Clicking on a complicated element in page using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I want to select the `label` tag that has an `input` tag with value=14860 and click on it.

What do I need to use for this in Selenium ?

The normal `By.id`, `By.tagName` don't seem to be working. So I will probably have to use `CSS selector` or `XPath`, but not sure how to do it or if there is a better way to do it.

In the case of using `CSS selector` or `XPath`, is there some `Chrome` extension that automatically provides the `CSS selector` or `XPath` so one could directly use it in code?

[image]

Comment: //input[@value='14860'] would be a simple xpath.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan, one small change. I want to click on the button on the page which has that input tag. I tried fetching the input element, but that is not clickable. I think I will need toselectt the label tag so that click is possible

Comment: /parent::label would do it

Answer (score 0):

regarding chrome extension that helps in selecting web elements try [TruePath](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/truepath/mgjhkhhbkkldiihlajcnlfchfcmhipmn) it gives you possibility to chose rom multiple selection options

and for selecting the input tag try the following Xpath:

```
//input[@value='14860'] 
//input[@data-question-id='3739']
```